# Admin in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm creating admin panel for my GAE application.

Here is part of my app.yaml

```
- url: /admin/.*
  script: admin.application
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: myApp.application
```

And Here is part of my my admin.py:

```
class AdminPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, Admin')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', AdminPage),
], debug=True)
```

If I'm not logged in I get "Current logged in user test@example.com is not authorized to view this page." message, which is what I wanted.

I get 404 error when I try to go to myApp/admin/ while logged in as admin and I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: What do you mean by `myApp/admin/`?  wouldn't it be `localhost:8080/admin`?

Comment: @mgilson I think he meant it to be like a mini-CMS, delete posts, edit things, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your application doesn't have a rule for `/admin/`. You'll need to change your `application` to this:

```
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/admin/', AdminPage),
], debug=True)
```

When you go to `/admin/`, the `login: admin` part of your `app.yaml` shows the login error before it ever hits your `admin.py` file if you're not logged in. When you are logged in, the application tries to find a url matching `/admin/`, but the only configured url is `/`.

Comment: @dragonx That would match, but it's probably not a great thing to do in this case. Matching like that would return the AdminPage instead of a 404 when it would be more appropriate to do so. Additionally, having a canonical URL for a resource is always a good idea (this also allows you to take advantage of the `webapp2.uri_for` function). I'd use the `RedirectRoute` with `strict_slash=True` as well to get the behavior of redirecting from a missing or extra trailing slash to the configured URL (e.g. `/admin` -> `/admin/`), but that's just an opinion on how routing should behave.